# change product image url in widgets & shop page

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to setup CDN on woocommerce theme. Here's what I have added to the **functions.php**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_html', 'replace_content' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', 'replace_content' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'replace_content' );
```

The above code works fine on single product page but not on woocommerce widgets and shop page.

How can I use **add_filter** to apply the CDN url to all images loaded by woocommerce?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a plugin such as [CDN Enabler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cache-enabler/) which will change the URL of all your static files to point to the CDN URL. This works for all your images, CSS/JS files, etc.